# C# Class Definition

Tags: c#, objective-c, class, xamarin.ios

In XCode and objective c, if I want to use a UIGlassButton in interface builder, I put the following line in my header file:

```
@class UIGlassButton;
```

I am now using monotouch c#.  Is there a similar statement I can use to import the UIGlassButton class?

I guess the question becomes did the Monotouch team port UIGlassButton to C# and Monotouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you don't import a class, but a namespace. For instance, class may be defined as:

```
namespace Ui.GlassControls
{
  public class UIGlassButton
  {
   .... // methods, properties, whatever

  }

}
```

In the source file that requires the button, you would use:

```
using Ui.GlassControls; // namespace reference

....
// inside of some class
UIGlassButton ugb = new UIGlassButton();
// or
Ui.GlassControls.UIGlassButton ugb = new Ui.GlassControls.UIGlassButton();
```

the second instantiation method bypasses the need for a "using" statement, since it refers to the control by its fully qualified namepspace.controlName identifier.

**Note** I'm not familiar with UIGlassButton specifically, so you'll have to search to figure out what assembly it's defined in, and what file you need to reference from the calling project.

Comment: You'll likely have to look at MonoTouch's documentation to figure out exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks David.  UIGlassButton is undocumented, so I don't know where to look.